# Formula translation for Mars perturbers in Python

Tags: python, formula

In the process to calculate Mars hours I need to translate certain formula to obtain the Mars perturbers (PBS).

That formula is: PBS = Σ(i=1,7) Ai cos [ (0.985626° ΔtJ2000 / τi) + φi]

where A is the amplitud, τ the period and φ the phase according to the value of i, in this table (7 values for each parameter):
[Table with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d4X8.png)

ΔtJ2000 is the offset from J2000 epoch, and I´m pretty sure I already have the right value, which is *6603.452757146675* when that formula needs to be calculated.

So, this is the piece of code I´m using:

```
A = [0.0071, 0.0057, 0.0039, 0.0037, 0.0021, 0.0020, 0.0018]
tau = [2.2353, 2.7543, 1.1177, 15.7866, 2.1354, 2.4694, 32.8493]
phi = [49.409, 168.173, 191.837, 21.736, 15.704, 95.528, 49.095]

OffsettJ2000 = 6603.452757146675

PBS = 0
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    PBS += A[i] * math.cos(0.985626 * OffsettJ2000 / tau[i] + phi[i])
```

The result for PBS should be around 0,00219º (taken for MarsTime 1.2 app), but I´m getting 0.00048º

What´s my mistake? Thanks from a martian!

Editing to add a useful link with all the processes and formulas from NASA (mine is B-3): https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/mars24/help/algorithm.html

digitalmeteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cite degrees in your text, but you call a function (`cos`) that works in radians.  Try converting:

```
angle = 0.985626 * OffsettJ2000 / tau[i] + phi[i]
PBS += A[i] * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
```

Comment: That (was) my mistake. Thanks Prune, now it´s working.